# Isomorphisms of quotient rings of $\mathbb{Q}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to familiarise myself with isomorphisms of quotient rings. More specifically, I am trying to find out which of the following three relations hold:

1. $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^3-1) \cong \mathbb{Q}[i\sqrt{3}]$
2. $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^4-4) \cong \mathbb{Q}[i, \sqrt{2}]$
3. $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^4-6X^2+9) \cong \mathbb{Q}[i, \sqrt{3}]$

I would appreciate a lot if someone could explain how to proceed in those kind of exercises. I have heard that proving that two structures are not isomorphic is usually done by looking for invariants such as nilpotent or idempotent elements which only appear in one of the structures. However, in practice, I find it very hard and time-consuming to find such elements. Is there an easier way, which might also be more suitable if this kind of exercise appears in multiple choice questions?

Comment: An easy criterion for non-isomorphism is when one of the rings is an integral domain and the other one is not.

Comment: So you mean looking for zero divisors? Is it correct that since $(X-1)(X^2+X+1) \equiv 0 mod (X^3-1)$, $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^3-1)$ is not an integral domain, and thus $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^3-1)$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[i \sqrt{3}]$ @AnneBauval

Comment: Correct. Do the same for the two other questions.

Comment: Since $\mathbb Q[X]$ is a *PID*, and $X^3-1$ is not irreducible, therefore $(X^3-1)$ is not a prime ideal, forcing the quotient ring unable to be a domain.

Answer (score 1):

None of the isomorphism relations hold as all the polynomials in the quotient rings are reducible, which means none of the quotient rings are integral domains, while all the rings on the right-hand side are fields.

For example, $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^{4}−6X^{2}+9)\not\cong \mathbb{Q}[i,\sqrt{3}]$ because $X^{4}−6X^{2}+9$ factors as $(X^{2}-3)^{2}$. Thus, $(X^{2}-3)$ is a zero divisor, showing that the quotient ring is not an integral domain.

A similar argument takes care of the remaining two cases.